# Is there are way to change value inside of AlertDialog.Builder?(Android)

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, inner-classes, final

I'm new to android.
Can I change the value inside of AlertDialog.Builder?

```
int changeThisDataToOne = 0;

    new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext())
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setTitle("Are you sure?")
            .setMessage("Do you want to delete this note?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            changeThisDataToOne = 1;
                           //error : Variable 'changeThisDataToOne' is accessed 
                           //from within inner class, needs to be declared final
                        }
                    }
            )
            .setNegativeButton("No", null)
            .show();
}
```

Comment: can you make the variable as class variable?

Answer (score 0):

change `changeThisDataToOne` to `final int[]`,

```
final int[] changeThisDataToOne = {0};
```

then its value can be changed as

```
changeThisDataToOne[0] = 1;
```

or make `changeThisDataToOne` as field variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access local variable(**changeThisDataToOne**) into inner class ,you should make it final or initialize it as global variable.